# Trying to get ng-include working

Tags: angularjs

Learning angular and trying to get a very simple ng-include to work.
tempHeader.html contains a single line of text, which fails to display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="theApp">
  <head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ng-include src="tempHeader.html"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-include` expects a variable, so you have to wrap your string in quotes:

```
<ng-include src="'tempHeader.html'"/>
```

Or set a variable and use that:

```
$scope.url = "tempHeader.html";
<ng-include src="url"/>
```

Comment: Still nothing coming from the tempHeader.html file, tried extra quotes and 

    <body>
      I am here
      <script>
        $scope.url = "tempHeader.html";
      </script>
      <ng-include src="url"/>
    </body>

Comment: I can browse both temp.html and tempheader.html, they reside in the same folder

Comment: Hmmm, I was getting a $scope undefined, changed the code to the double set of quotes and now it's working in this simple case, thanks!